# How to call a macro inside a macro depending on conditions

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro called "Comparison" that compares values from current period with the previous period, and it's working fine.

Edit to explain better: The macro Comparison will compare values from a specific account (revenues, for example) for the month T and T-1. All inside that macro works fine.

Say the current period is T. If the current month is March, June, September or December (Q1, Q2, Q3 or Q4), then I want to compare values from period T with T-1, T-1 with T-2 and T-2 with T-3. If the current month is not in the first condition, then I will only compare T with T-1. There's a variable called YEARMONTH (that can be 202210, for example) that I declare in another part of the code.

So basically I'm trying to run the Comparison macro 1 time if it's not the end of a quarter, or 3 times if it's a quarter.

I'm trying to do it as follows:

```
%MACRO TEST(YEARMONTH); /*20XXYY*/
%LET MONTH = %SUBSTR(&YEARMONTH,5,2);
%LET CP = &YEARMONTH.;
%LET CP_1 = &YEARMONTH. - 1;
%LET CP_2 = &YEARMONTH. - 2;
%IF &MONTH. = 3 %THEN %DO; %LET CP_3 = &YEARMONTH. - 91; %END
%ELSE %DO; %LET CP_3 = &YEARMONTH. - 3; %END;
%IF &MONTH. IN (3, 6, 9, 12) %THEN %DO;
    %Comparison(CP,CP_1);
    %Comparison(CP_1,CP_2);
    %Comparison(CP_2,CP_3);
%END;
%ELSE %DO;
    %Comparison(CP,CP_1);
%END;
%MEND TEST;
```

Basically I can't test it in SAS as my profile was mistakenly blocked by IT (they were meant to revoke my access to some libraries, but they revoked everything linked to SAS). Considering that the macro "Comparison" is working, will that new Macro work or are there flaws in my code?

Comment: So the macro %comparison() takes as input the NAMES of the macro variables to compare?  Or should you instead be passing in the VALUE of the macro variables?

Comment: Tom, it takes the values. If I run it manually it should be %Comparison(202210,202209), for example. Now taking a look at my code I notice I should've written %Comparison(&CP.,&CP_1.) instead?

Comment: Is YEARMONTH supposed to be a string representing four digit year and two digit month?  If you subtract 1 from that when the month is January you are going to get a nonsense string with month digits of 00.

Comment: Oooh, yes! I covered it in only one case, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works a lot easier if you convert your YYYYMM string into an actual date.  You have to use & before the macro variable name to pass in the values. You never defined CP_3 macro variable.  You can just use the MOD() function to test if it is the last month of a quarter.

```
%macro test(yearmonth); 
%local date month cp cp_1 cp_2 cp_3 ;
%let date=%sysfunc(inputn(&yearmonth,yymmn6.));
%let month=%sysfunc(month(&date));
%let cp = %sysfunc(putn(&date,yymmn6.));
%let cp_1 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&date,-1),yymmn6.);
%let cp_2 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&date,-2),yymmn6.);
%let cp_3 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&date,-3),yymmn6.);
%comparison(&cp,&cp_1);
%if %sysfunc(mod(&month,3)) = 0 %then %do;
  %comparison(&cp_1,&cp_2);
  %comparison(&cp_2,&cp_3);
%end;
%mend test;
```

Let's make a dummy %COMPARISON() macro and test it;

```
317  %macro comparison(one,two);
318    %put &=one &=two;
319  %mend;
320
321  %test(202201)
ONE=202201 TWO=202112
322  %test(202203)
ONE=202203 TWO=202202
ONE=202202 TWO=202201
ONE=202201 TWO=202112
```